# This line of code is supposed to generate exponential service times, but I am not able to get the logic behind it

Tags: matlab, random, distribution, exponential

This line of code is supposed to generate exponential service times, but I am not able to get the logic behind it.

```
% Exponential service time with rate 1
mean = 1;
dt   = -mean * log(1 - rand());
```

This is the [source link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simevents/examples/m-m-1-queuing-system.html), but MATLAB is needed to open the example.

I was also thinking if `exprnd(1)` will give the same result of generating numbers from the exponential distribution that has a mean of 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right!

First, note that MATLAB parameterizes the Exponential distribution by the mean, not the rate, so `exprnd(5)` would have a rate `lambda = 1/5`.

---

This line of code is another way to do the same thing:
`-mean * log(1 - rand());`

This is the [inverse transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) for the [Exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution).

If *X* follows an Exponential distribution, then
[image]

and rewriting the [cumulative distribution function (CDF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) and letting *U* ~ Uniform(0,1), we can derive the inverse transform.

[image: Derivation of the Exponential inverse transform]

Note the last equality is because 1-*U* and *U* are equal in distribution.  In other words, 1-*U* ~ Uniform(0,1) and *U* ~ Uniform(0,1).

---

You can test this yourself with this example code with **multiple approaches**.

```
% MATLAB R2018b
rate = 1;                % mean = 1       % mean = 1/rate
NumSamples = 1000;

% Approach 1
X1 = (-1/rate)*log(1-rand(NumSamples,1));  % inverse transform

% Approach 2
X2 = exprnd(1/rate,NumSamples,1);      

% Approach 3
pd = makedist('Exponential',1/rate)    % create probability distribution object
X3 = random(pd,NumSamples,1);
```

[image: Histograms showing all three approaches]

---

**EDIT:**  The OP asked is there was a reason to generate from the CDF rather than from the [probability density function (PDF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function).  This is my attempt to answer that.

The inverse transform method uses the CDF to take advantage of the fact that the CDF is itself a probability and so must be on the interval [0, 1]. Then it is very easy to generate very good (pseudo) random numbers which will be on that interval. The CDF is sufficient to uniquely define the distribution, and inverting the CDF means that its unique "shape" will properly map the uniformly distributed numbers on [0, 1] to a non-uniform shape in the domain which will follow the probability density function (PDF).

You can see the CDF performing this nonlinear mapping [in this figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling#/media/File:Inverse_transformation_method_for_exponential_distribution.jpg).

One use of the PDF would be [**Acceptance-Rejection**](https://planetmath.org/acceptancerejectionmethod) methods, which can be useful for some distributions including custom PDFs (thanks to @[pjs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2166798/pjs) for jogging my memory).

Comment: This was a really great answer, cleared all my doubts. Is there any reason we chose to generate samples of the distribution from the CDF, and not from the PDF?

Comment: @user3656142 , I've edited my answer to address you comment -- great question.  I hope it helps.  Basically, it is just a computationally low-cost approach.

Comment: PDF based solutions can be done using acceptance/rejection techniques, but require the ability to generate from a scaled bounding function with finite area.  For distributions with an infinite range, finding a suitable bounding function can be challenging and tends to be less intuitive than using the inverse transform approach.  Ironically, exponentials are often used as a bounding function in such cases since they're easy to generate with inversion.

Comment: @pjs Yes, Acceptance-rejection has been useful some cases for me. Not sure how I didn't think of that.  Answer updated.  Thanks.